# Как восстановить пароли и настройки Google Chrome после переустановки windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, пароль

Переустанавливал **Windows** и перед этим сохранил папку с настройками **Google Chrome** по пути

> C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\

но без синхронизации и без входа в гугл аккаунт. 
Теперь, после переустановки ОС, установки чистого хром и замены папки Default вижу такую картину
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
пароли не подтянулись, настройки частично, подтянулись только закладки. Как восстановить все?
Сами пароли можно вытащить с помощью программы [chromepass](https://chromepass.ru.uptodown.com/windows), но вводить их теперь каждый раз вручную?.. (у меня их более 100) или все же есть какой-то более автоматический способ подтянуть пачкой?